# What responsibilities are to comply C\C++ standard?

Tags: c++, c, gcc, stm32, c11

Little bit stupid question.
For example I've read, that in C11 was added support of threads. 
Then, for example GCC compiler for my STM32F4 said, that it supports C11 standard. 
So, does it mean now, that without OS I'll achieve threading support??? But how it can be?

Another example - g++ for STM32 supports std::vectors, and IT WORKS,even without OS's memory management.
This mean that some memory manager is inside compiler? Or not?

Comment: There must always be some kind of underlying support. Even if there's no OS there might be underlying platform-specific code in libraries that handles things like memory or simple multitasking. Without knowing more than your compiler version (which we don't) and what software or other support libraries you link with it's impossible to say anything.

Comment: most likely you're looking at a socalled "stand-alone" compiler tool chain. C++11 has core language features (expect them to be there) and library features (expect them to be spotty/absent). Also "memory management" is always a libc task. The OS must have some rudimentary process model (even if it is is just "the memory is all yours")

Comment: C11 thread support is optional and an implementation might define `__STDC_NO_THREADS__` to indicate `threads.h` is not supported.

Comment: [C11 7.26.1/2](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.26) "Implementations that define the macro `__STDC_NO_THREADS__` need not provide this header nor support any of its facilities."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> So, does it mean now, that without OS I'll achieve threading support???

It means that the language is specified so that multi-threaded programs can be written correctly, with well-defined synchronisation when accessing shared data; and that a full hosted implementation should provide the thread library. It doesn't mean that all implementations will allow multiple threads: that will depend on support from the underlying system.

> This mean that some memory manager is inside compiler?

Yes, typically the language run-time includes a heap manager. It will be assigned some memory (either obtained from the OS, or allocated in some other system-dependent manner, perhaps simply as a static block when the program starts), which it then splits into smaller lumps to support dynamic allocation within the program.

Answer (score 7):

There are two kinds of C implementations — *hosted* implementations, which provide the standard library, and *freestanding* implementations, which only need to provide the core language and a minimal number of headers.  Implementations for embedded systems are usually freestanding.  This is described in detail in Section 4 of [the C11 spec](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf).

What is more, there are a number of features that can be omitted even in a hosted implementation.  In particular, thread support is optional (a hosted implementation that omits thread support must define the macro `__STDC_NO_THREADS__`).  This is described in Section 6.10.8.3 of the spec.